# Issues with accumulo 1.4.3 helloworld example on CDH4.3 QuickStart

Tags: java, hadoop, accumulo

I am trying to put together a accumulo/cloudera quickstart. Accumulo is running, but I am having problems attempting to execute samples, namely hellowworld.

It appears it is finding hadoop and not accumulo classes?

Following is execution and error messages. I appreciate your assistance!

```
./bin/accumulo org.apache.accumulo.examples.simple.helloworld.InsertWithOutputFormat "instance" localhost:2181 "username" "password" hellotable

Thread "org.apache.accumulo.examples.simple.helloworld.InsertWithOutputFormat" died nulljava.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.accumulo.start.Main$1.run(Main.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.util.ContextFactory.createTaskAttemptContext(ContextFactory.java:131)
    at org.apache.accumulo.examples.simple.helloworld.InsertWithOutputFormat.run(InsertWithOutputFormat.java:56)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.accumulo.examples.simple.helloworld.InsertWithOutputFormat.main(InsertWithOutputFormat.java:76)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21594680/accumulo-zookeeper-hadoop-installation-instructions-downloads-and-versions-for ?

Comment: Solved, problem was permissions in shell and permissions to accumulo files

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by:
1) Using cdh4 accumulo-1.4.3 tar
2) adding additional users
3) ensuring write permissions on supporting jars