# accumulo, zookeeper hadoop Installation instructions, downloads and versions for CENTOS 6

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper, centos5, accumulo

I would appreciate guidance on accumulo, zookeeper hadoop Installation instructions, downloads and versions for CENTOS 6.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: It looks like this has already been answered on the Cloudera Community Forums. http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Storage-Random-Access-HDFS/Possible-Accumulo-1-4-3-compatibility-issues-with-hadoop-2-0-in/m-p/5835

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the installation via cloudera manager version 5. I recently installed accumulo using the same.

Here is the [link](http://archive.cloudera.com/cm5/installer/) for Cloudera manager 5.

You can use [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CobVqNMiqww) Youtube video as reference.